# Object property databinding to a collection item based on a Name of an object

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, data-binding, observablecollection

Is it possible to implement the following WPF (Silverlight) databinding scenario?

There are a number of CustomControls on a page:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
  ...
  <My:CustCntr x:Name="name1" Property1="{Binding Property1}" />
  <My:CustCntr x:Name="name2" Property1="{Binding Property1}" />
  <My:CustCntr x:Name="name3" Property1="{Binding Property1}" />
  ...
</Grid>
```

The Grid's `DataContext` is an ObservableCollection:

```
grid1.DataContext = myCollection;
...
ObservableCollection<MyEntity> myCollection= new ObservableCollection<MyEntity>();
...
```

The `MyEntity` class has properties `Name` and `Property1`.

```
 MyEntity me1 = new MyEntity { Name = "name1", Property1 = "5" };      
 MyEntity me2 = new MyEntity { Name = "name2", Property1 = "6" };
 MyEntity me3 = new MyEntity { Name = "name3", Property1 = "7" }; 
 ... 
 myCollection.Add(me1); 
 myCollection.Add(me2);
 myCollection.Add(me3); 
 ...
```

**Can I establish databinding for `Property1` in each of my CustomControls to a corresponding item of the myCollection where `Name` of the CustomControl equals the value of `Name` field of the collection item?**

Comment: I have an idea about ItemsControl, but I need additional information: 1. How do you use the x:Name property? 2. Is the Grid control necessary or it can be replaced by a StackPanel?

Comment: @vorrtex 1. x:Name property of CustomControls is used for identifying and handling them in code. 2. I see your point. No, the layout can be much more complicated than just using a Grid like that. So, it's impossible to replace it by a StackPanel.

Comment: Is Xaml Binding required or would code behind be ok? Because I can't see any way of doing this in Xaml

Comment: @Meleak I'm doing the updating of them in code now, using `FrameworkElement.FindName(string name)` construction. Just wanted to optimize it in more WPF-ish way. So, if it is a databinding way, then it can be in code, I think.

Comment: So the number of controls on the page is constant, right? Because otherwise there is no point in using the Name property. In this case I can set bindings in code-behind using linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally what you do in a situation where you have a Collection that you want to display on the UI is to use an `ItemsControl`, `ListBox` etc. and set the ItemsSource to the Collection. Example

```
<ItemsControl Name="itemsControl1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <My:CustCntr Property1="{Binding Property1}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now the DataContext for each `CustCntr` will be an instance of `MyEntity` and the Binding will be set between `CustCntr.Property1` and `MyEntity.Property1`

---

That said, I'm not sure of the reasons for your current implementation so if you want to create Bindings based on Name I think you'll have to resort to code behind

**Xaml**

```
<Grid Name="grid1" Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
    <My:CustCntr x:Name="name1" />
    <My:CustCntr x:Name="name2" />
    <My:CustCntr x:Name="name3" />
    <!--...-->
</Grid>
```

**Code behind**

```
public ObservableCollection<MyEntity> MyCollection
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

**Update**
Call this method, SetBindings, everytime you've modified the collection in code. Also, use the Loaded event for the Grid instead to set all bindings when it's first Loaded.

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SetBindings();
}
private void SetBindings()
{
    foreach (UIElement element in grid1.Children)
    {
        if (element is CustCntr)
        {
            CustCntr custCntr = element as CustCntr;
            foreach (MyEntity myEntity in MyCollection)
            {
                if (custCntr.Name == myEntity.Name)
                {
                    Binding property1Binding = new Binding("Property1");
                    property1Binding.Source = myEntity;
                    property1Binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                    custCntr.SetBinding(CustCntr.Property1Property, property1Binding);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Helpful answer! I didn't know about the possibility to set WPF Binding in code. So, it's very helpful for me. Thanks! +1. Though, I tried to implement this approach, but my custom controls got updated only once - initially. When I'm further trying to update the source collection, nothing happens, no updating of controls take place. Maybe the `property1Binding.Source = myEntity;` isn't enough for the Binding to remember the particular item in the collection where `custCntr.Name == myEntity.Name` ?

Comment: @rem: Is Property1 a Dependency Property? Otherwise, does the class `MyEntity` implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and does Property1 raise PropertyChanged in the setter? In that case, the Binding should work both ways. If you make changes to the Source Collection, like add/remove, then you'll have a missmatch between the Custom Controls in the UI and the Collection. Can you maybe add some more info on this?

Comment: @Meleak Thank you for your help! Yes, `Property1` was a Dependency Property. As you suggested, `MyEntity` didn't in fact implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I've implemented it now, but so far with no success. So, regarding your note about possible missmatch between the Custom Controls and the Collection: the fact is, the Collection is now updated by removing all the items and adding the same collection of items but with new values. Can it be the cause of the problem?

Comment: @rem: Ok, if it is a Dependency Property you don't need to raise the PropertyChanged event so that should be fine. If the Controls are re-added they should raise the Loaded event again. Can you verify this by adding a breakpoint in the `CustCntr_Loaded` eventhandler? Does it get hit? Also, make sure the source collection contain the matching items before re-adding them

Comment: @Meleak Sorry, it seems my previous comment was a little unclear. It isn't the CustomControls that are removed and re-added. It is the ObservableCollection `MyCollection` that is totally cleared up and then refilled by the same number of records but with new values. I suspect that maybe because of this refilling of `MyCollection` DataBinding might not be working?

Comment: @rem: Yes, that's the problem right there. I'll update my answer

Comment: @rem: Updated my answer, call that method everytime you're done changing the source collection

Comment: @Meleak Your answer together with your helpful comments is great! I wish I could upvote it more than once. Hope the Community'll do that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

No, that would not be posible.
You could however use an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28VS.95%29.aspx) object (there are multple controls that inherit from it), but it might be harder to set the design up then. No for the individual controls, but for the placement of each CustCntr.